# Is there any way to generate unit test automatically without Visual studio enterprise in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am writing unit test for developed code I am using Visual studio ultimate 2013 is there any method to generate unit test automatically.

Comment: A combination of pex and moles (see @Priyanka Subramani's comment) and a coverage tool will get you near

Comment: is it hard to google?and ofc there is no way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have fully automatically generated tests in a test suite, however there are some test suites like [IntelliTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823749.aspx) that can generate code for you if you provide a description on what to test and how to test it.

However it will just be very basic stubs/tests that gets generated for you and you will have to write the meaningful tests on your own. The computer has no knowledge on what you want to test, which edge cases that needs to get covered and how extensive the testing should be.